# Fast retrieving Information Coded in Alphanumeric

Tags: orientdb

Is there a way to use OrientDb for performance efficient retrieving Information Coded in Alphanumeric? (something like `PatriciaTrie` from `apache.commons`)

For example searching `"st*"` should returns me all words started with `"st"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a LUCENE index for that.

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Full-Text-Index.html